# how to resize only object but not pattern

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabricjs for my canvas editing and I have a pattern with 1000x200 pixels of image and I am drawing circle with 200px radius filled with the pattern. I have remaining 800px of image width hidden. now I would like to resize the circle object in such a way that it resizes without stretching the pattern until it reaches the remaining 800px and then it stretches as usual.

Please some one suggest the best way to do that.

Comment: If you resize object by dragging on canvas it doesn't change its size properties but the scale ones, so maybe try to change width/height instead of scaleX/Y. It's just a suggestion - I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom filter for that, I don't think this will work using the default patterns.